# How to ask for permissions in Android for communicating with .so binary in Unity

Tags: unity

I am trying to load stockfish android binary for the android App.

```
 string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "stockfish.android.armv7.so";
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(filepath);
        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            WWW executable = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + "stockfish.android.armv7.so");
            while (!executable.isDone)
            {
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, executable.bytes);

            //change permissions via plugin

        }
        //code to get permissions to communicate with .so file
```

Stock fish location

```
Assets/Plugins/Android/stockfish-10-armv7.so
```

stockfish location in Android build

````
/data/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject/files/stockfish.android.armv7.so```
````

adb logcat log

```
02-13 10:41:17.798: E/Unity(15538): Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.DefaultCompany.NewUnityProject/files/stockfish.android.armv7.so', CommandLine='', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= mono-io-layer-error (0)
02-13 10:41:17.798: E/Unity(15538):   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Any ideas for handling such a case will be helpful. Thanks in Advance

I think my logic for Getting permission is broken. I have no idea how I can do it. if someone can help how to do it from scratch. will be helpful